# Is it possible to load the rails environment into Textmate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I spend alot of time in rails console, but when I have something to work out that doesn't involve rails it's even easier to create tests at the bottom of the .rb file, and just command-R to run it in Textmate.

It would be amazing and really speed up my workflow if I could do the same with classes that depend on my rails environment being loaded.  Is there an include I could temporarily put in a file that would load what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this both with rails 2 and 3 by requiring "./config/environment.rb".